# Rails query records based on attribute of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a query based on an attribute of an associated record but am failing miserably

I've the following models:

```
class CompanyPay < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ee_pay
  has_many :pay, :through => :ee_pay 
end

class EePay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company_pay
  has_many :pay
end

class Pay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ee_pay
  has_one :company_pay, :through => :ee_pay
end
```

I'm trying to create a query that returns all Pay objects where the attribute `apply_paye` on their associated CompanyPay is `true`.

I've been trying to get my head around joins, scope, lambdas etc since yesterday but I'm just confusing myself more at the stage.

The query I want would be something like this but I just don't know how to phrase it properly

```
@records = Pay.where(employee_id: current_employee.id, {|p| p.company_pay.apply_paye == true}).order(:id)
```

Can anyone help me out. Can I write a one line query? Should I be using a join? Should a lambda be used?

Thanks for looking

> **Edit 1**

I've edited the original post as I gave the wrong attribute name by mistake (should be `apply_paye` not `taxable`).

Tried the following query provided by fylooi

```
@records = Pay.joins(:ee_pay => :company_pay).where(:pay => {:employee_id => current_employee.id }, :company_pay => {:apply_paye => true})
```

But am getting the following error:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PayLinesController#update

    PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "pay" LINE 1: ...any_pays"."id" = "ee_pays"."company_pay_id" WHERE "pay"."emp... ^ : SELECT "pays".* FROM "pays" INNER JOIN "ee_pays" ON "ee_pays"."id" = "pays"."ee_pay_id" INNER JOIN "company_pays" ON "company_pays"."id" = "ee_pays"."company_pay_id" WHERE "pay"."employee_id" = 1 AND "company_pay"."apply_paye" = 't' ORDER BY "pays"."id" ASC
```

> **Edit 2 - Solved**

Pluralising the table names in the query worked, as per the suggestion from David Aldridge.

This is the final query:

```
@records = Pay.joins(:ee_pay => :company_pay).where(:pays => {:employee_id => current_employee.id }, :company_pays => {:apply_paye => true})
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Pay.joins(:ee_pay => :company_pay).where(:company_pay => {:taxable => true})
```

Comment: Where do I put my other query parameter 'employee_id: current_employee.id'?

Comment: `.where(:pay => {:employee_id => current_employee.id }, :company_pay => {:taxable => true})`

Comment: Cant get that to work. I gave the wrong attribute name on `company_pay`. It's actually called `apply_paye`. The error I'm getting is `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "pay" LINE 1: ...any_pays"."id" = "ee_pays"."company_pay_id" WHERE "pay"."emp... ^ : SELECT "pays".* FROM "pays" INNER JOIN "ee_pays" ON "ee_pays"."id" = "pays"."ee_pay_id" INNER JOIN "company_pays" ON "company_pays"."id" = "ee_pays"."company_pay_id" WHERE "pay"."employee_id" = 1 AND "company_pay"."apply_paye" = 't' ORDER BY "pays"."id" ASC`

Comment: Pluralise the table names in the where clause: where(:company_pays => {:taxable => true})

Comment: Or you could define a class method on CompanyPay named "is_taxable" defined as "where(:taxable => true)", and then use "Pay.joins(:ee_pay => :company_pay).merge(CompanyPay.is_taxable)". That would keep the logic of whether a CompanyPay instance is taxable or not within its own class.

Comment: Thanks so much. The pluralised table names worked. I'll have to do more work on joins as I don't fully get them. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but is there a way to get a less than clause into `:pay => {:employee_id => current_employee.id }` statement. I want to have something like this `:pay => {:employee_id => current_employee.id , :period < current_period.period}`

Comment: Think I solved it. I appended `.where(['period <= ?', current_period.period])` to the end of the statement and it's working